# Finding Code in QGIS Select Features Toolset

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-2, select

Can anyone tell me in what directory the pre-installed Python scripts for the QGIS selection tools (i.e., Select by Point, Select by Polygon) are found?  I am using on a Windows 7 installation of QGIS 2.0.1.

Comment: These may not be Python scripts ...

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I found them in the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\python\plugins
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know which of the directories specifically?  I have db_manager, fTools, GdalTools, and processing in the plugins directory.